# Trying to read in a.txt file with a scanner but keep getting FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filenotfoundexception, readfile

I keep getting the FileNotFoundException in java. I have the file name exact with the .txt extension and the .txt file is in the same folder along with my .java files. I'm not sure whats going on here and I have tried multiple things.

Here is my main class where im trying to print each command with the index number before by calling commands class.

```
public class mainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      commands fileCommands = new commands();
      for (int i = 0; i >= fileCommands.getLength() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println("" + i + ": " + fileCommands.getCommand(i));
        }
```

Here is the commands class.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class commands {

ArrayList<String> commandList;

public Commands() throws Exception {
    this.commandList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("commands.txt"));

            while(s.hasNextLine()) {
                commandList.add(s.nextLine());
            }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
 }


public int getLength() {
    return commandList.size();
}

public String getCommand(int pIndex) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    return commandList.get(pIndex);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've got the scanner working now and reading in the file. I've debugged it and see it putting each command in the arraylist. Now the for loop in the main method isn't printing at all.

Answer (score 0):

When it is compiled and run the `.java` files become `.class` files and I am pretty sure the source of them is in a different location, therefore you still need to specify the location of your text file:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("path-to-text-file/commands.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid to load files like this. This will not work in a variety of scenarios.

Instantiate the `Scanner` like this instead:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(commands.class.getResourceAsStream("commands.txt"));
```

Just a side note: the naming convention for classes in Java is that the name should start with an upper case letter.